# Redirect .co.za to .com - 2 domains sharing the same root folder and htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have 2 domains:

**mysite.co.za** and **mysite.com**

the **mysite.co.za** domain is an addon domain which shares the same root directory as the mysite.com domain.  So both **mysite.co.za** and mysite.com load the same website files.

Is there perhaps a way that I can redirect the **.co.za** addon domain to the **.com** via the `.htaccess` file even though both domains share the same `.htaccess` file?

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect entire domain names through your DNS provider. I recommend that approach, doing it on the domain server level would probably evoke better performance than having to traverse all the way to your server for the re-direct.

Comment: Clear your cache. Then refresh.